# Piecewise function not recognised by MATLAB

Tags: matlab, piecewise

Im trying to set up a symbolic expression V using the symbolic variable x like:

```
V = piecewise(x<=0.5, 2*x, x>0.5, 2-2*x)
```

However MATLAB doesn't even recognise this command although it is mentioned in their documentation.

The error it keeps returning is:

```
Undefined function or variable 'piecewise'.
```

I searched online for this error message, and some names like MuPad Notebook kept popping up, but I don't know what those mean either. I do have the Symbolic Math Toolbox ( I checked using `which privResolveArgs`).
Finally, Im using MATLAB 2016a if that helps.

Thanks for all the help, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `piecewise` function is available starting from MATLAB version 2016b. In 2016a you have to use the function [`heaviside`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/heaviside.html):

```
syms y(x)
y(x)= heaviside(x-0.5)*(2-2*x)+heaviside(0.5-x)*2*x
```